# Dynamic UIPickerView menu(s)

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I'm trying to create an app that uses 2 text fields and 1 picker view. The picker should pop up once the user clicks in the first text-field. After the user makes a selection from the menu and clicks in the second text field, the picker pops up again but with a menu dependent on the text in the first text field (previous choice).

The problem I'm having is when the picker shows up when the second field is clicked (after the first choice is made and shown in the first text bow), the menu doesn't show the second stage of choices.

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var textField1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var textField2: UITextField!

var activeTextField = 0

@IBOutlet var picker: UIPickerView!

var characters = ["Letter", "Number"]
var letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
var numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    picker.hidden = true
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {

    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    if (textField == textField1) {

        activeTextField = 0

    }
    else if (textField == textField2) {

        activeTextField = 1

    }

    picker.hidden = false

}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

    return 1

}


func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    if (activeTextField == 0) {
        return characters.count

    }
    else if (textField1.text == "Letter") {
            return letters.count
    }
    else if (textField1.text == "Number") {
        return numbers.count

    }


    return component
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    picker.hidden = true
    if (activeTextField == 0) {
        textField1.text = characters[row]
        picker.reloadAllComponents()
    }
    else if (textField1.text == "Letter") {
            textField2.text = letters[row]
    }
    else if (textField1.text == "Number") {
            textField2.text = numbers[row]


    }

}


func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {

    if (activeTextField == 0) {
        return characters[row]

    }
    else if (textField1.text == "Letter") {
            return letters[row]
        }
    else if (textField1.text == "Number") {
        return numbers[row]

    }

    return nil
}


deinit {
    self.picker.delegate = nil
    self.picker.dataSource = nil
}
    }
```

I also want to point out that after clicking a couple of times, then scrolling through the picker and making a selection, the menu stays the same (still shows "Letter" and "Number") but the actual value selected is "correct". Please help me make this work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function `textFieldDidBeginEditing`, before calling `picker.hidden = false`, reload the pickerview.